# Is there an equivalent to sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants for non-waiting queries?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Basically I have a proc that executes and requires massive amounts of memory. We can sometimes get into a situation where the proc executes multiple times, in which case the memory grants are visible in sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants, because theyre waiting to be fulfilled.

We're trying to refactor the query so that it doesnt need such large amounts of memory, but its hard to get a baseline because we have to put the server in an unusable state to get the info from sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants. Is there an equivalent to this view for any currently running query, not just those waiting or that have waited for grants? We're using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You can run [sp_whoisactive](http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry42453.aspx) and look for `[used_memory] column` --> `combination of both procedure cache memory and workspace memory grant`. You can [log the output to a table](http://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/) as well. I believe for any currently running query, `sys.dm_exec_requests` -->  `granted_query_memory` column will give you `Number of pages allocated to the execution of a query on the request`.

Comment: Yeah but, for example, this query requests 97gb of memory (1TB under "Ideal grant") in dm_exec_query_memory_grants, but sys.sysprocesses and dm_exec_requests says it only needs/uses 3 pages. I feel like there is extra memory allocated but not viewable in those views/tables. I also doubt the 3 pages because theres 1 billion rows in just one of the tables, and I'm asking for top 10,000,000 rows back. Good suggestion though, I did try those :)

Comment: @Kin I actually misread `sp_whoisactive` as `sp_who2 active`. That looks promising but its going to be really difficult for me to get that approved for our production environment. I am going to give a read through and see if I cant figure out how he's determining `used memory`, because clearly if he can find out, there is a sys table somewhere that holds that data, or multiple tables that hold peices of it. Thanks!